# Does anyone recognize this temple in SE Asia?

Tags: thailand, identify-this, southeast-asia

I'm trying to figure out what this temple is called and where it's located.  Does anyone know?

[image]

Comment: @jptokal have you created a tag wiki excerpt for ayutthaya?

Comment: Post apocalyptic London gherkin?

Answer (score 31):

Looks like [Wat Chaiwatthanaram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wat_Chaiwatthanaram) in Ayutthaya, Thailand, north of Bangkok:

[image]
(courtesy [Justin Vidano via Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sunset_at_Wat_Chaiwatthanaram,_Ayutthaya,_Thailand.jpg))

While the tubular central Khmer-style *prang* does indeed look a bit like Angkor Wat, the red brick is distinctively different and the tilted *chedi* dome (right in the original, far left in the photo above) and the brick terraces all around are giveaways.

And for once, this answer was not derived through Google image search, but actually having visited: Ayutthaya's temples have quite a distinctive look!

Comment: Wow, that's a really impressive answer.  I'm guessing the OP's photo was taken from the east side and this one from the northwest corner.

Comment: It's a gorgeous area with an interesting history.  A friend's dad used to teach there, and told stories about how when he started (50+ years ago), most of the temples and buildings you can see now were simply covered in jungle.  He said he walked through tall grass to & fro to teach with a long stick beating the grass ahead of him to clear snakes.  If you get a chance to go, it's well worth the trip just for the history, architecture and statuary.